# How to enable `dbox` for a particual mail account?

Tags: linux, postfix, email-server, dovecot

I need to enable [http://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailboxFormat/dbox/](http://textuploader.com/xg9h) for`mailarchive` account.

I want to enable `dbox` only for the `mailarchive` account & the other accounts continue to use the `Maildir` format.

Please check the output of `doveconf -n` [here](http://textuploader.com/xg9h)

Answer (score 4):

Use the optional [**`mail`**](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/UserDatabase) field in your user database to override the global [**`mail_location`**](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailLocation) and use that to set the dbox format as an exception for the mailarchive account .

**Edit:** Since you're using LDAP you'll have to change the LDAP filter in Dovecot to include retrieval of an attribute to use as the mail field:

```
user_attrs = homeDirectory=home, uidNumber=uid, gidNumber=gid, mailLocation=mail
```

and populate the `mailLocation` attribute for the mailarchive user in your [LDAP user database](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/AuthDatabase/LDAP/Userdb) with the correct value for a [dbox](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailboxFormat/dbox):

```
mailLocation=sdbox:~/dbox
```

NB The mailLocation attribute used in the Dovecot docs is AFAIK not a default attribute in OpenLDAP but you can of course select any custom unused extension attribute or extend the schema with something custom.

Comment: can u please be more descriptive? as I'm pretty new to this domain having a hard time to understand, though I got the basic idea, some example will be really really very helpful.

Comment: The [manual](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailLocation) has examples for each of the user database backends (since you didn't specify which you use, I can't give a more specific answer.)

Comment: I'm using ldap.

Comment: @HBrujin If I share with you the output of `doveconf -n` will you be able to help? Beacuse I'm still stuck with same. I am geeting no clue no where in internet.

Comment: If you can't get it to work you might ask yourself if continuing with this is worthwhile or if you can live without the benefits of dbox. In other words, what is the actual problem you're trying to solve and might there be an alternative solution? -  Editing your question and adding that information from `doveconf -n` *might* help. You may also retract your acceptance of my answer as the correct one because that reduces the likelihood that you will get additional answers.

Comment: @HrBrujin, as you suggested I have made change in `dovecot-ldap.conf.ext` as [this](http://textuploader.com/xg9h) and in `/etc/dovecot/auth-ldap.conf.ext` as [this](http://textuploader.com/xg9p) but the error I'm getting as follows 

 `Ambiguous mail location setting, don't know what to do with it: yes (try prefixing it with mbox: or maildir:)`